# How to get installed JRE/Java version in IE10 using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, activex, internet-explorer-10

I want to run applets in **IE10** which requires a least version of **java 1.7.0_51**.

So before loading applet, I want to check the current installed jre version and display a proper message if the current jre is not suitable.

So to do this we are using **deployJava.js**  (https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt).

In this we are calling **getJREs** function to get the all available jres.
But its returning an empty list.

After debugging we found in **testUsingActiveX** function its not able to create **ActiveXObject** for version 1.7.0, though the version is installed.
Its throwing exception and returning false.

Is there any work around or a better way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`navigator.plugins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins). I believe it's supported by every major browser, even with older versions. I've tested it with latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE.

Here's a function which returns Java Deployment Toolkit version:

```js
function getJavaVersion() {

    // note the extra space, it's used to make split easier
    var jdtString = 'Java Deployment Toolkit ';
    var jdtIndex = -1;
    // find index of JDT inside navigator.plugins
    for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++)
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name.indexOf(jdtString) >= 0)
            jdtIndex = i;

    if (jdtIndex === -1)
        return null; // Java Deployment Toolkit was not found

    return navigator.plugins[jdtIndex].name.split(jdtString)[1];
}
```

This returns Java version number, for example `8.0.50.13`, or `null` if JDT was not found. Using this number, you can parse out specific version number and compare it to required version.

Comment: Hi @maremp, This works fine with FF and chrome. But when i tried it with IE10 its returning null. also navigator.plugins.length is giving as zero, so its not going inside loop.

Comment: Worked the same for me with a quick test. But are you sure java is enabled inside ie? Because in my case it wasn't.

Comment: Yeah its enabled in IE. when i run it, it's showing a popup with a button 'AllowBlockedContent'. After clicking it, its returning null. I'm running it on windows 7 64 bit with java 1.7.0_55 64 bit.  I tried with 32 bit java version also, but still no luck.